# two rows using label tag

Tags: html

I am just trying to show data in a two column field and want to avoid using table tags.

However, the data comes out like this: http://jsbin.com/ewixe5/

how can I change it so they are displayed properly?

Comment: what does properly mean?

Comment: why do you want to avoid table tags?

Answer (score 1):

Make .show_label an inline-block.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k6skr/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like an unordered list (ul), like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

and declare the style like:

```
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
}
```